# Getting a number following a substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following string:

`var str = "row 13213 applecare!teddytest!minervahasppv - 125";`

and I would like to extract the number after the 'row' (13213), I tried:

```
str = str.replace(regExWhiteSpace, '');
rowMatch = /row([0-9]+)/g.exec(str);
rowNumber = rowMatch[1];
```

It does the work, however if the string is like:

`var str = "row 13213 456applecare!teddytest!minervahasppv - 125";`

The number would be 13213456, and I don't want that.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Just match `(?<=\brow +)\d+`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/hBTiFB/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, finally we have a lookbehind in regular expressions. But it's still a new feature and may not be available on the client. [caniuse lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind) Just warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove whitespace, match optional whitespace between `row` and 1+ digits:

```
var rowMatch = /row\s*(\d+)/.exec(str);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DOwwGu/1), `\s*` will match any zero or more whitespace chars.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var str = "row 13213 applecare!teddytest!minervahasppv - 125";
var rowMatch = /row\s*(\d+)/.exec(str);
if (rowMatch) {
 console.log( rowMatch[1] );
}
```